# Google script oauth authentication against twitter requre authorization every day

Tags: twitter, oauth, google-apps-script

I have written a simple google script function to get followers and save them in database. Next I ve set up trigger to run the function every day at midnight but I got the error I got to authorize in order to run the function.

```
function get_followers() {
   // Setup OAuthServiceConfig
   var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService("twitter");
   oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("http://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token");
   oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("http://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token");
   oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize");
   oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
   oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
   var options =
      {
        "oAuthServiceName" : "twitter",
        "oAuthUseToken" : "always"
      };

  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&count=5000",options);
  var dataAll = Utilities.jsonParse(result);
  db_save(dataAll,'twitter_followers');
  Logger.log(dataAll);
 }
```

When I run the code from script.google.com Twitter authorization pop-up appears and the function is executed. And than when the function is running via the trigger it looks like for the first time is running correctly and than I have to authorize the script again.

How can I authorize it permamently?

I know it's possible as I have Drupal integrated with the same twitter account and I had to authorize it only once?

Any thoughts? Should I store the oAuthConfig variable to make it permament? Any hints?

Comment: Were you able to figure out this? Am stuck with exactly the same problem

Answer (score 2):

It seems that Twitter recently updated the accepted characters contained in tweets. For instance if you try to post a single quote (`'`), your tweet will be rejected by the API and your access token revoked. You will therefore have to re-identify yourself each time.

So look at the symbols contained in your tweets and try to remove `(`, `)` and `'` to debug and see if the problem comes from that.

More info about that [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2936#c12).

Comment: [see also issue 3046](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3046#c10) `For APIs that do require RFC 3986 encoding (such as Twitter v1.1+) there is currently no workaround, other than to ensure the following characters don't appear in your URL or parameters:  []!'()*'`

Comment: I had the same exact problem as the OP and could finally solve it by removing the characters specified by @Taifun. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

For some unknown reason, the OAuthService of Google Script works well only if you use saved ScriptProperties for CONSUMER_KEY and CONSUMER_SECRET. I guess its needed by Google Script to save the token. Here's what worked for me:

```
oauthConfig.setConsumerKey(ScriptProperties.getProperty("CONSUMER_KEY"));
oauthConfig.setConsumerSecret(ScriptProperties.getProperty("CONSUMER_SECRET"));
```